# After reboot swap turns off issue

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, swap

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I have a problem with my swap partition. I resized swap with GParted. When partitioning, I had to turn swap partition off. After resizing it, I put it back to active (ON) state.

When I rebooted my laptop, the swap partition is OFF. I have to turn it on after every reboot. How can I permanently enable swap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal.

Use `sudo lsblk -f` to get a list of partitions and mountpoints. / is the mountpoint for your ubuntu partition and [SWAP] tells you on which partition swap is. (example: sda1 / and sda2 [SWAP]).

Now use `sudo blkid` to list partitions and their UUID. (example: /dev/sda1 UUID:"2904d822-ebc9-4d33-8529-e17138380e88" TYPE="ext4" and /dev/sda: UUID="ff0f94c6-c126-4c40-8290-1ed828c49c19" TYPE="swap")

This is if I understand correctly your /etc/fstab:

`# # <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>`

`proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0`

`# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation`

`# /windows was on /dev/sda6 during installation`

`# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation –`

Edit the /etc/fstab file with the information from the output of the commands earlier. In the terminal type `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` and edit the file. The following is an example:

`# # <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>`

`proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0`

`# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation`

`UUID=2904d822-ebc9-4d33-8529-e17138380e88 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1` (put this on one line)

`# /windows was on /dev/sda6 during installation`

`# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation –`

`UUID=ff0f94c6-c126-4c40-8290-1ed828c49c19 none            swap    sw              0       0` (also on one line)

The only things you'll have to change from the example are the UUID numbers. Keep the rest of the example and the rest of /etc/fstab

Reboot and all should be well.

Comment: I have no UUID in the /etc/fstab file, this what I have:  # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
# /windows was on /dev/sda6 during installation
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation

Comment: I've edited the answer with your new information.

Answer (score 0):

While installing Ubuntu, I defined swap partition but got same problem and solved like that;

```
-- list blocks 
root@kerem:~# blkid 
/dev/sda1: UUID="4e098809-7c30-41b2-99d6-c548c50a3108" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="f10cb0a9-0310-4318-883c-b38506bc8942" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="f1514d98-d032-49f4-a027-0677cc83dc14" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="ccb4a3ef-1b9d-4639-a16b-aee762c074ba" TYPE="ext4" 

-- enable swap on proper partition 
root@kerem:~# swapon /dev/sda5

-- edit crypttab 
root@kerem:~# nano -w /etc/crypttab
-- commenting out this line 
# cryptswap1 UUID=f10cb0a9-0310-4318-883c-b38506bc8942

-- edit fstab 
root@kerem:~# nano /etc/fstab
-- commenting out second line below
# UUID=e657f6df-a346-46ec-b201-0d4d2f5e5b1c none            swap    sw              0$
# /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0 
-- added this line 
/dev/sda5 none swap sw 0 0

-- restart computer
root@kerem:~# reboot
```

Credits: https://superuser.com/a/22190/178001

Answer (score 0):

For AWS EC2 Instance store swap volumes, you may have to re-enable the swap after stopping and re-starting your instance.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-store-swap-volumes.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu!  Links are great, but if they get moved or deleted your answer becomes useless.  Please quote the website rather than just providing a link.